# Как сконвертировать потомка сына в родительский класс, не потеряв значения переменных?

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Здравствуйте!

Есть вот такая иерархия:

```
class RigidBody{
    ...
    protected:
        sf::FloatRect rect;
};

class Item : public RigidBody{ ... };
class Block : public Item{ ... };
```

По отдельности все классы работают нормально. Но если я конвертирую `Block *[]` в `RigidBody **` для обработки физики внутри родителя, значение переменной `rect` не сохраняется (обнуляется):

```
Block *blocks[20];

...

RigidBody **bodys = (RigidBody **)blocks;
```

Как это поправить? Спасибо!

UPDATE: updatePhysics

```
void RigidBody::updatePhysics(sf::Time dt, RigidBody **bodys, int numBodys){
        float elapsed = dt.asSeconds();

        if(this->dynamic){
            this->velocity.x += this->acceleration.x * elapsed; // NOTE: Maybe I'll need to add gravity by x
            this->velocity.y += this->acceleration.y * elapsed + GRAVITY;

            if(abs(this->velocity.x) > this->maxVelocity.x){
                this->velocity.x = ((this->velocity.x > 0) ? 1 : -1) * this->maxVelocity.x;
            }

            if(abs(this->velocity.y) > this->maxVelocity.y){
                this->velocity.y = ((this->velocity.y > 0) ? 1 : -1) * this->maxVelocity.y;
            }

            this->rect.left += this->velocity.x * elapsed;
            this->rect.top += this->velocity.y * elapsed;
        } else {
            this->velocity.x += this->acceleration.x * elapsed;
            this->velocity.y += this->acceleration.y * elapsed;
            this->rect.left += this->velocity.x * elapsed;
            this->rect.top += this->velocity.y * elapsed;
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < numBodys; i++){
            this->checkCollisionAndResolve(bodys[i]);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 2: checkCollisionAndResolve

```
bool RigidBody::checkCollisionAndResolve(RigidBody *object){ // TODO: add other collision types support
        bool isColliding = this->rect.intersects(object->rect);

        if(object->bodyType != RIGIDBODY_NONE && isColliding){
            sf::Vector2f centers[2];

            centers[0] = object->getCenter();
            centers[1] = this->getCenter();

            int distanceByX = (centers[0].x - centers[1].x) / (object->getWidth() / 2);
            int distanceByY = (centers[0].y - centers[1].y) / (object->getHeight() / 2);
            int absoluteDistanceByX = abs(distanceByX);
            int absoluteDistanceByY = abs(distanceByY);

            if(abs(absoluteDistanceByX - absoluteDistanceByY) < 0.1f){ // Corner collision
                if(distanceByX < 0){
                    this->rect.left = object->getRight();

                    if(this->velocity.x < 0){
                        this->velocity.x = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    this->rect.left = object->getLeft() - this->getWidth();

                    if(this->velocity.x > 0){
                        this->velocity.x = 0;
                    }
                }

                if(distanceByY < 0){
                    this->rect.top = object->getBottom();

                    if(this->velocity.y < 0){
                        this->velocity.y = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    this->rect.top = object->getTop() - this->getHeight();

                    if(this->velocity.y > 0){
                        this->velocity.y = 0;
                    }
                }

                if(rand() % 2){
                    this->velocity.x = -this->velocity.x * object->getRestitution();
                } else {
                    this->velocity.y = -this->velocity.y * object->getRestitution();
                }
            } else if(absoluteDistanceByX > absoluteDistanceByY){ // Side collision
                if(distanceByX < 0){
                    this->rect.left = object->getRight();
                    this->velocity.x = 0;
                } else {
                    this->rect.left = object->getLeft() - this->getWidth();
                    this->velocity.x = 0;
                }

                this->velocity.x = -this->velocity.x * object->getRestitution();
            } else { // Bottom or top collision
                if(distanceByY < 0){
                    this->rect.top = object->getBottom();
                    this->velocity.y = 0;
                } else {
                    this->rect.top = object->getTop() - this->getHeight();
                    this->velocity.y = 0;
                }

                //this->velocity.y = -this->velocity.y * object->getRestitution();
            }
        }

        return isColliding;
    }
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NdC0DHaG - заголовки... http://pastebin.com/4MB7wkLU - вызов

Comment: Да. Но тип меняется. И из-за этого значения переменных обнуляются.

Comment: Конкретно `rect` обнуляется при приведении к `RigidBody **`.

Comment: Возможно, вы ещё не читали: [mcve]

Comment: У Вас в вопросе `sf::FloatRect rect;` - `protected`, а в pastebin - `public`. Это опечатка или код - не тот? Покажите значение `rect` до и после строки `RigidBody **bodys = (RigidBody **)blocks;` - добавьте в вопросе вокруг этой строки код с выводом `rect`.

Comment: ....Опечатка... До строки `RigidBody **bodys = (RigidBody **)blocks;` `rect` = {128, 128, 16, 16}. После: {0, 0, 0, 0}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас получается неопределённое поведение, другими словами Ваш код неправилен. Давайте разбираться: у Вас есть массив указателей на `Block` который Вы *насильно* приводите к двойному указателю на `RigidBody`. Попробуйте привести это с помощью `static_cast` — не выйдет и это уже должно Вас насторожить.

Так вот, привели мы значит к `RigidBody**` и теперь перемещаемся по массиву: тут всё нормально, т.к. массив указателей, то и проблемы нет — какой бы ни был указатель, его размер всегда одинаков(почти, но это тут не принципиально). Проблема начинается дальше, у Вас выполняется вот эта строчка:

```
this->checkCollisionAndResolve(bodys[i]);
```

Что такое `bodys[i]`? Это указатель на `Block`. А функция об этом знает? Нет конечно, для неё это указатель на `RigidBody`! И всё бы было хорошо, и это бы даже работало, да вот только вместе с `Item` в наш объект пришёл указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций и всё поломал. Нельзя просто так трактовать указатель на `Block` как указатель на `RigidBody`, нужно преобразовывать. А функция об этом ничего не знает, вот Вы и имеете, то, что имеете.

Мораль первая: никогда не преобразуйте массивы типов, в другие типы это никогда ничем хорошим не заканчивается.

Мораль вторая: никогда не используйте преобразование в C стиле, оно только прячет от Вас ошибки.

Comment: а как тогда мне выполнить проверку физики? Писать отдельные методы для классов `Item`, `Block` и других потомков?

Comment: @reload, придётся подумать как это организовать. Мне сложно что-то сказать, не видя всего кода. Всегда можно провести унификацию, не скатываясь до повторения кода. Просто нужно придумать как.

Comment: > Мораль вторая: никогда не используйте преобразование в C стиле, оно только прячет от Вас ошибки.

То-есть только через `static_cast <>`?

Comment: @reload, можно и через другие C++ операторы преобразования, чтобы было очевидно, что происходит. `static_cast` наиболее безопасен.